# How do I perform tag driven cross-browser testing in Cucumber for Java?

Tags: java, cucumber, bdd, cucumber-jvm

I want to run a scenario in multiple browsers by tagging it with the desired browser(s).

**For example:**

```
Feature: Smoke Test
    @Chrome @Firefox
    Scenario: the site should launch in all browsers
        Given the site is online
        When I navigate to site
        Then the site should display in all browsers
```

I am currently able to run tests on one browser at a time with:

```
Feature: Smoke Test
    @Chrome
    Scenario: the site should launch in all browsers
        Given the site is online
        When I navigate to site
        Then the site should display in all browsers

    @Firefox
    Scenario: the site should launch in all browsers
        Given the site is online
        When I navigate to site
        Then the site should display in all browsers
```

**How can this be implemented? Or, if it cannot, why?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you use JUnit to run your scenarios you can use `@CucumberOptions` to specify which tags to execute, and use separate test classes for the two tags:

```
@RunWith(Cucumber.class)
@CucumberOptions(tags = "@Chrome")
public class ChromeTest { }

@RunWith(Cucumber.class)
@CucumberOptions(tags = "@Firefox")
public class FirefoxTest { }
```

Launching of the browser should be possible with scenario hooks, which can also specify to which tags they apply:

```
@Before("@Chrome")
public void launchChrome() {
}
```

Comment: As it turns out, this does not produce the exact results I was looking for. However, it does answer my question, and greatly increases my understanding of how Cucumber works. Thank you.